# Is it possible to stop or restart a ros node at run time?

Tags: ros

Is it possible to start three nodes A, B, and C at the same time, stop only A in the middle, and then restart the stopped A?
I'm wondering if the stop and restart triggers can be dynamically changed using dynamic reconfigure, but I don't know how to stop and restart the node.
I use the ROS melodic.
Thanks!

Comment: You could use the launch file parameter ```respawn=true``` and kill the node to restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROS is intended for all nodes to run continuously until shutdown. Nevertheless there are some ideas that may help you to find a workaround:

- You could use system() in your code. Use this with wisdom since there are some use cases where use this call is [not recommended](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/).
- The [launch files](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/ros/Launch%20Files.html) will help you to starting and stopping nodes programmatically. Check roslauch API, more concretely the [Node Arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/API%20Usage#Node_Arguments).
- At least for killing there is an xmlrpc shutdown call, which is what rosnode kill uses. Sending SIGINT would also be OK as ROS installs a SIGINT handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can launch all three nodes using ROS Launch.

In case if you want any node to restart then you can use

```
respawn="true"
```

For example; launch file:

```xml
<roslaunch>
  <node name="foo" pkg="package" type="node" respawn="true" />
</roslaunch>
```

You can read more about it in the following links:

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

https://answers.ros.org/question/38808/can-nodes-be-made-to-automatically-restart-on-segmentation-faults/

In case if you want the code to start and restart on runtime, then you can also subscribe to a specific topic and accordingly, you can send the data on that topic to start/stop/restart the node and the node can simply perform that action in a separate thread.